# Qt subdir project structure

Tags: qt, qmake

My project structure is currently this:

```
-project
|--apps
   |--app1
   |--test
|--libs
   |--lib1_subdir
      |--lib1_lib
      |--lib1_test
         |--test1
         |--test2
      |--lib1_examples
...
```

It works fine and dependencies are easily managed with simples

**libs.pro**

```
libs2.depends = lib1
```

**libs1.pro**

```
tests.depends = lib
```

is there a way to structure the project as follow keeping a clean dependencies structure?

```
-project
|--app
   |--app1
|--lib
   |--lib1
   |--lib2
|--tests
   |--test_lib1
   |--test_lib2
   |--test_lib3
|--examples
   |--ex_lib1
   |--ex_app1
...
```

subdir project can specify dependencies only for the same directory, cmake is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

> subdir project can specify dependencies only for the same directory

Of course, no. Simply use another level of indirection:

```
SUBDIRS = lib1 lib2 lib1_tests
lib1_tests.depends = lib1
lib1_tests.subdir = ../tests/test_lib1
# and so on
```

Comment: Well, in this way you do are including lib1_tests in that subdir, this means lib1_tests appears 2 times in the project hierarchy. This should means too if I'm going to compile from the top level hierarchy the project will be tried to be compiled 2 times, am I wrong?

Comment: @Moia SUBDIRS implements that dreaded "recursive make" pattern. Hence, it knows nothing about inter-project dependencies. This is something you have to provide as an extra step. And an additional no-op "make -C xxx" usually is not too expensive. But, of course, you can "optimize" some stuff. That's your choice.